# QGIS 3.10 on Ubuntu | Add Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, ubuntu

```
iface.addVectorLayer("vector_path","vector_name","ogr")
```

This code does not rename the layer as "vector_name". This should not be happening, right? Is there a work around?

Comment: Take a look here : https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading of the [manual](https://qgisapi.gitlab.io/qgisremote/reference/iface.addVectorLayer.html) I would say that it is good practice to use the names of the parameters if any are missing, so:

```
iface.addVectorLayer("vector_path",baseName="vector_name",providerKey="ogr")
```

Comment: Not the guy asking the answer. Tested by curiosity and not working as I would expect e.g give you "vector_name myfilenamefrompathwithoutextension". When you create then add the layer like in the link from J. Monticolo comment, it works the way I expect e.g layer name show only "vector_name".

Comment: @J. Monticolo's way is the way I would usually do it too.